How do I make make scrapfly authenticated to able to access protected routes on a website
I am trying to reveal the numbers of the ads on leboncoin.fr using a web scrapper but I have to be authenticated to be able to do that. There is a button that allows you to click to reveal the number. When you click on the button and you are authenticated the phone number is fetched from the server and revealed otherwise you are redirected to the login page.  My challenge here is how to add make the bot authenticated this the code. It gets the html content perfectly but because I am not authenticated, the clicking doesn't show the number. You can check page out here https://www.leboncoin.fr/ad/voitures/2858300144
 const scrapfly = new ScrapflyClient({
    key: "MY-API-KEY",
  });
  const result = await scrapfly.scrape(
    new ScrapeConfig({
      url: "https://www.leboncoin.fr/ad/voitures/2858300144",
      asp: true, // enable scraper blocking bypass

      render_js: true,
      js_scenario: [
        {
          click: {
            selector:
              "document.querySelector('button[title=\\'voir le numéro\\']').click()",
          },
        },
      ],
    })
  );
  // access scraped result data
  console.log(result.result.content);
  await writeFile("./hello.html", result.result.content);
  // and even process it with CSS selectors:
  await writeFile("./main.json", JSON.stringify(result.result));

I have tried adding the headers from my authenticated browser but it now gets blocked by the anti bot protection system on leboncoon.fr

const scrapfly = new ScrapflyClient({
    key: "MY-API-KEY",
  });
  const result = await scrapfly.scrape(
    new ScrapeConfig({
      url: "https://www.leboncoin.fr/ad/voitures/2858300144",
      asp: true, // enable scraper blocking bypass
      headers: {
        authority: "api.leboncoin.fr",
        path: "/api/call-tracking/v1/classified/2858300144/phone?referrerId=bc164284-9789-41f6-90bb-3c70c9b7beef&referrerType=alu",
        scheme: "https",
        accept: "*/*",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br, zstd",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        authorization: "Bearer jwt",
        "content-type": "aplication/json",
        cookie:"cpokie value",
        origin: "https://www.leboncoin.fr",
        riority: "(u = 1), i,",
        referer: "https://www.leboncoin.fr/ad/voitures/2858300144",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
        "user-agent":
          "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux aarch64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.188 Safari/537.36 CrKey/1.54.250320",
      },
      render_js: true,
      js_scenario: [
        {
          click: {
            selector:
              "document.querySelector('button[title=\\'voir le numéro\\']').click()",
          },
        },
      ],
    })
  );

